# Refreshing Marquee Text on Android

Tags: android, textview, marquee

On launch, my marquee text is working normally. Then i want to update text in somewhen. I get text on internet and set it to textview:

```
marqueeText.setText(Html.fromHtml(GetNew.getNews()));
```

There is no problem about getting text from internet. But then the text is not sliding. What is the problem about that? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I get this log when try to refresh it. I refresh it in a thread.

```
06-12 10:25:04.403: E/tag(498): Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the handler for working on UI thread.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(new Callback() {

        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            marqueeText.setText(Html.fromHtml(GetNew.getNews()));
            marqueeText.setSelected(true);
            marqueeText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And when you want to update the text in thread then use `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`

Answer (score 0):

i think u have not added in activity

```
 marqueeText.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The marquee on TextView will only scroll if the TextView is either in the selected or focused state

try `TextView.setEnabled(true) or TextView.requestFocus() or TextView.setSelected(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update view from threads other than the UI thread.