# scrolling marquee with updating text

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView with text which is updated by Runnable every 10 sec. After adding marquee effect I got a problem. When text updates it blinks and appears in other position. How can I make it just change the letters?

```
        TextView oneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneText);
    oneText.setSelected(true);


    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String bigstring = "Some text here";
                oneText.setText(bigstring);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 20 * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };


            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oneText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="@string/someString" />
```

Comment: you are describing an issue so you need to put the code in your Q to have a look.

Comment: have a look here for a possible solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994900/refreshing-marquee-text-on-android